# When I use ember.js and rails, nginx conf how to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ember.js

My project design like this,  `/team` url and `/team/*` will use `ember.js`. The other also use `rails`, and I set nginx conf:

```
upstream project {
  server unix:///tmp/project.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.project.io;
  root /home/deploy/www/project_backend/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://project;
      break;
    }
  }

  location /team {
    alias /home/deploy/www/project_frontend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
  }
}
```

But this had some problems, when I use `/team/` and will go to `project_frontend` index and `/team/check/` or `/team/project/check` will go to rails page.

I don't know what's wrong with my `.conf`, Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use `=` and `try_files` fix this problem.

```
upstream project {
  server unix:///tmp/project.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.project.io;
  root /home/deploy/www/project_backend/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://project;
      break;
    }
  }

  location /team {
    alias /home/deploy/www/project_frontend/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /team/;
  }

  location = /team/ {
    alias /home/deploy/www/project_frontend/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
  }
}
```